# Counting integer solutions

Tags: combinatorics

how many integer solutions are there to the equation

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 24$

where $x_1 \ge 0, x_2 \ge 1, x_3 \ge 2, x_4 \ge 3$

I have no idea how to go about this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $z_1=x_1, z_2=x_2-1, z_3=x_3-2, z_4=x_4-3$, then your equation becomes
$$
 z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4 = 18
$$
where $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4\ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. That was exactly the hint I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a generating function.

We have the constraints $f_{1}(x)$ for $x_{1}$ is $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{i} = \frac{1}{1-x}$. For $x_{2}$, we have a minimum of $1$, so we start $f_{2}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x^{i} = x * \frac{1}{1-x}$.

For $x_{3}$, we get $f_{3}(x) = x^{2} \frac{1}{1-x}$. And for $x_{4}$, we get $f_{4} = x^{3} \frac{1}{1-x}$.

Multiplying these generating functions together gives us $x^{6} (\frac{1}{1-x})^{4}$. And so we look for the coefficient of $x^{24}$. Dividing out by $x^{6}$ allows us to satisfy the count with the coefficient of $x^{18}$. So using our binomial identity, we get $\binom{18 + 4 - 1}{18}$ as the count.

Note this is also the Stars and Bars problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)